# Retrieve a list of tags from a Gerrit repository from a Python application

Tags: git, python-2.7, gerrit

I have a Python application that needs to retrieve a list of all tags from a git repository hosted on Gerrit. The source code in the repository should not be world readable, the tags however are fine. It would also be OK to embed the credentials of a user in the Python application, if that user can only read the tags of the specific repository.

We access git through ssh using public key authentication.

The application is packaged with PyInstaller and needs to run on both, Linux and Windows.

What I have considered so far:

1. Parse gitweb available through Gerrit

   This was implemented before we switched to Gerrit.
   However, access to gitweb allows a user to read much more than just tags.
2. The [Gerrit REST API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html).

   However, this only allows [listing branches](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#list-branches), not tags.
3. Use the equivalent of `git ls-remote` from a Python git library.

   However, the python git libraries I looked at rely on the native git command line tool, which I don't want to bundle with the application. (Also because it would be difficult to do platform independently.)
4. Write a Gerrit plugin that allows listing of tags.

   I have not tried this, but if there is no easier solution, this will be it.

Any pointer, also to options I already considered is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if there any API to retrieve tags directly from remote. But you can do this by cloning repo locally.

Comment: Through what protocol are the gits made available – SSH, HTTP(S), or the native Git protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [Dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/) and [pygit2](http://www.pygit2.org/) are native Python implementations of Git, but glancing over their API documentation it's not clear how to do the equivalent of `git ls-remote` with either of them.

If the gits are served via HTTP(S) you can use a simple request to get the available refs. The protocols are documented in [Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt) in the Git source code.

Comment: Gerrit does support serving git over http to specific users. I will look into your second suggestion.

Comment: I ended up using urllib2 and parsing the git http protocol myself, which is fairly easy in this case. The next problem is now that Gerrit does not allow restricting a user to read tags only...

Comment: Indeed, you can't have a read-restricted git that still exposes all tags. Also, Gerrit hides a tag unless you have read access to at least one branch that can reach that tag.